# SMOTE isn't helping with logistic regression reults - for imbalanced data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, smote

I have a dataset that is highly imbalanced, talking about 230 cases of class `1` in the target feature, and more than 3800 of class `0`.  I used SMOTE to resample and then built a logistic regression model. Logistic regression seemed prefect to me for this kind of data since it's a binary target feature. The results aren't much better after applying SMOTE.

Here is the code :

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

smote = SMOTE()
X_train_resampled , Y_train_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X_train,Y_train)

# Make predictions using the model

logisticModel = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train_resampled, Y_train_resampled)
Y_pred = logisticModel.predict(X_test)

## Scoring the model
logisticModel.score(X_test,Y_test)

print(classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred))
```

#### Confusion matrix after SMOTE:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      0.74      0.85       942
           1       0.11      0.75      0.19        40

    accuracy                           0.74       982
   macro avg       0.55      0.75      0.52       982
weighted avg       0.95      0.74      0.82       982
```

#### Before SMOTE:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      0.69      0.81       934
           1       0.11      0.75      0.19        48

    accuracy                           0.69       982
   macro avg       0.55      0.72      0.50       982
weighted avg       0.94      0.69      0.78       982
```

So as you can see, the precision hasn't got any better, only the recall, slightly. SMOTE is one of the best metrics and I've used it previously, however in this case I seem to miss something.

What should I do?

Comment: maximize roc-auc instead which also maximizes pr-recall

Comment: Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling, undersampling or weighting will not solve this non-problem:
[Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: Don't use accuracy, precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, or the F1 score. Every criticism at the following threads applies equally to all of these, and indeed to all evaluation metrics that rely on hard classifications:
[Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
[Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)
[Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Comment: Instead, use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).

Comment: [Profusion of threads on imbalanced data - can we merge/deem canonical any?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352)